# JavaScript does not work on page reload [Rails]?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view

This is my JavaScript:

```
function showQuestion(id) {
  $(".question").hide();
  $("#"+id).show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  current_question=1;
  showQuestion(current_question);
  $("#next_question").click(function(){
    alert('The current question is '+current_question);
    current_question=current_question+1;
    showQuestion(current_question);
  });
  $("#prev_question").click(function(){
    alert('The current question is '+current_question);
    current_question=current_question-1;
    showQuestion(current_question);
  });
});
```

And this is my `show.html.erb` [my Rails view]:

```
<div id="questions">
  <% @questions.each_with_index do |q,i| %>
    <div id="<%= i + 1 %>" class="question">
    <strong><%= q.body %></strong>
    <% if q.type == "MultipleChoice" %>
      <% q.choices.each do |choice| %>
        <br /><%= radio_button_tag "question#{q.id.to_s}", "choice#{choice.id}", @answer == choice  %>&nbsp;<%= choice.body %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <table>
    <tr><td><%= link_to "< Previous", '#', :remote => true, :id => "prev_question" %></td><td><%= link_to "Next >", '#', :remote => true, :id => "next_question" %></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So, when I click the 'Next' or 'Previous' button, it works. But after that, neither button works. I have a feeling it has something to do with jQuery not working. Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the JavaScript Console in your browser to check for errors there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close!

The problem is that you are generating a set of links for each question with the same IDs, which isn't correct.  It sounds like the first set of links is being hidden when you click one of them the first time.

One solution is to move the table with the Previous and Next links outside of the  tag that contains it.  Here's a fiddle showing a dumbed-down version of your code with prev and next links outside of the question div. http://jsfiddle.net/QNLF9/

You could also leave the links inside the question div, assign them a class and use a class selector in your jQuery code.  Here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/traDx/

I hope that helps.  One other little thing.  You should use html escape codes `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of `<` and `>` respectively.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the code correctly (I don't know ruby), your IDs should be unique.  You are creating many buttons all with the same ID.  jQuery is only attaching to the first (since there should only be one).

Try changing it to a class instead.  Or (probably better), remove the buttons from the loop and only create one set of buttons.

EDIT:  Also, while this is probably not causing the issue, IDs should not start with a digit, unless you're using HTML5 which I think may allow this.

Comment: @clem on the buttons (inside the loop) he has `:id => "next_question"` which to me seems to be setting the id to `next_question` for every iteration through the loop.  Then in his jquery he has `$("#next_question")` which gets only those element with the `id` of `next_question`.